# OpenGl renderer shows N/A on NVIDIA/INTEL GPU config with prime-select intel

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime

Details:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5916
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
           OpenGL: renderer: N/A version: N/A
```

Also,running

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. I haven't installed the xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe package because I've read that modesetting is a better option on newer Intel Cards like mine(Intel 620 kabylake graphics)

Further information:

```
uname -a
Linux anup-X556UQK 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What should I do to get the opengl renderer running properly?

Comment: running the same kernel, the package xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe doesn't exist for me, running a 630, everything works
I have the  xserver-xorg-video-intel package,
do you have nvidia-prime, what does prime-select query return?

Comment: `prime-select query` outputs
`intel` Intel gets selected properly. As for the hwe package , you need to add a ppa. Installing that intel driver package should fix this, but i want to use the mode-setting driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5916
       Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5
       drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
       OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
       version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.4
```

It worked with sudo for some reason. Looks like i do have openGL running properly.